# .pgpass file does not work as advertised

Tags: postgresql

(Debian 8)

My .pgpass file is at my home folder (admin)

I and using the right format as indicated in the documentation

hostname:port:database:username:password

The same fields I put there work well when put explicitly into the `psql` command line. (of course I have to enter the password manually).

However, running `psql` by itself gives our an error:

psql: FATAL:  role "admin" does not exist

Note that my sql username is NOT admin, which is my debian username.

What am I doing wrong? my goal is to get access to `psql` without having to use an elaborate command line including host/port/username/database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.pgpass` is not a way to choose which settings you want to use, it's a way to store passwords for a number of settings you've already chosen to use. It can contain multiple lines. The relevant line is then chosen as follows, according to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html):

> The password field from the first line that matches the current connection parameters will be used.

You still have to provide your connection parameters (besides the password).

If you always want to use the same connection parameters, you should probably use the [environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) (`PGHOST`, `PGDATABASE`, `PGUSER`, ...), and possibly place them in your `.bashrc` file (depending on the shell you use).

You can then choose to store the password itself in the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable or in the `.pgpass` file. The latter might give you a bit more flexibility.